# use alias in joinWith yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to connect a relation table, and and get the max value

```
$query->joinWith('hotelPrices')
  ->andWhere([HotelPrice::tableName() . '.price' => $form->prices])
  ->max(HotelPrice::tableName() . '.price');
```

but i get this error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'hotel_price'

how to me in this case to use alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you have used the same table alias ('hotel_price') in multiple places in your query. You can use a different alias for the 'hotel_prices' table in your join statement.

```
 $query->joinWith(['hotelPrices' => function($query) {
 $query->from(['hp' => HotelPrice::tableName()]);
 }])
 ->andWhere(['hp.price' => $form->prices])
 ->max('hp.price');
```

Comment: The use of closure just to add alias is unnecessary. `ActiveQuery::joinWith()` method provides it's own way to set the alias.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#joinWith()-detail), you can add alias by adding it to relation name. In your case:

```php
$query->joinWith('hotelPrices hp')
    ->andWhere(['hp.price' => $form->prices])
    ->max('hp.price');
```